# По мановению руки(,) (запятая)

Tags: запятые, правила

«По мановению руки хозяина дома(,) лакей подошел и подлил ему вина». 
Скорее всего, здесь запятая не нужна, поэтому если это так, то хотелось бы понять почему. Какое правило в русском языке говорит об этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***По мановению руки хозяина дома  //  лакей подошел и подлил ему вина.***

Запятая не ставится.

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов  факультативное. Чаще обособляются обороты с производными предлогами (*благодаря, вопреки, вследствие* и т.д.), а для обособления обычных предложно-падежных оборотов **нужны причины**: распространенность, удобная позиция, смысловое выделение, уточняющее или пояснительное значение и др.

В данном случае таких причин нет.

Эта тему можно почитать у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114